# PreparedStatement getting an object with 2 Strings

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm using MYSQL 5.6
when i try the code above, the ResultSet return null.

```
public Client viewClient(String clientName, String password) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM main.clients where client_name = ? and client_password = ?;";
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, clientName);
        pstmt.setString(2, password);// ;(1, clientID);
        ResultSet resultset = pstmt.executeQuery();
        pstmt.closeOnCompletion();
        while (resultset.next()) {
            return new Client(resultset.getLong("client_id"),
                    resultset.getString("client_name"),
                    resultset.getString("client_password"),
                    ClientType.valueOf(resultset.getString("type")),
                    resultset.getString("address"),
                    resultset.getString("email"),
                    resultset.getString("phone"),
                    resultset.getString("comment"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

even that in the code below using Statment the ResultSet return the Object.

```
public Client viewClient(String clientName, String password) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM main.clients where client_name = 'John' and client_password = '1234';";
     try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultset.next()) {
            return new Client(resultset.getLong("client_id"),
                    resultset.getString("client_name"),
                    resultset.getString("client_password"),
                    ClientType.valueOf(resultset.getString("type")),
                    resultset.getString("address"),
                    resultset.getString("email"),
                    resultset.getString("phone"),
                    resultset.getString("comment"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

There is a problem with my syntax? or there is a general issue with PreparedStatment? That i'm not aware of it?.
Thank you

Comment: did you check your sql script? I see this FROM main.clients. you're using alias or just a name of a table?

Comment: That looks fine other than that you don't need the `;` at the end of the statement (you do that in the interactive client, but not in code), but I've seen people do it and *think* it's harmless. If it weren't, I'd expect you to get an exception, not no results.

Comment: Does it need to use a `;` in the sql?  Also why use a while if your are returning?

Comment: Have you checked that the voalues of your variables are as expected?

Comment: Side note: Don't store actual passwords in the DB. (Your column and variable names *suggest* you're storing the actual password, but I could be wrong.) Store a hash of the password and check against that. This makes it harder for the information to be used for nefarious purposes.

Comment: Side note 2: There's no reason to use `closeOnCompletion` if you're using try-with-resources (which you are). The statement will be closed when execution leaves the try block.

Comment: Thank you all, the code is ok (even with the ; ) i had a problem in my main, that was a recrusive function that ask the object but in the sec call the parameters wasn't there so Excepstion was thrown, anyway i fix it. thank you T.J. for the side note .